# My PowerShell Script Not Working As Expected (for compiling C++ files)

Tags: c++, powershell, scripting

I am a C++ programmer. I wanted to automate the task of compiling, running and debugging of a program into one neat PowerShell script. But it unexpectedly throws unrelated error which I don't know why.

The program takes C++ file(s) as input, produces a compiled .exe file and runs the program, all at once. It also takes other little debugging options.

```
if (!($args.count -ge 1)) {
    Write-Host "Missing arguments: Provide the filename to compile"
    exit
}

$isRun = 1

$EXE_NM = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($args[0])
$GPP_ARGS = "-o " + $EXE_NM + ".exe"

$count = 0

foreach ($op in $args) {
    if ($op -eq "-help" -or $op -eq "-?") {
        Write-Host "Format of the command is as follows:-"
        Write-Host "cpr [filename.cpp] {additional files}"
        Write-Host "{-add [compiler options] (all options of -add should be in double quotes altogether)}"
        Write-Host "[-d (short for -add -g)] [-nr (do not run automatically)]"
        exit
    } elseif ($op.Contains(".cxx") -or $op.Contains(".cpp")) {
        $op = """$op"""
        $GPP_ARGS += " " + $op
    } elseif ($op -eq "-add") {
        if (($count+1) -ne $args.Count) {
            $GPP_ARGS += " " + $args[$count+1]
        }
    } elseif ($op -eq "-d") {
        $GPP_ARGS += " -g"
    } elseif ($op -eq "-nr") {
        $isRun = 0
    }

    $count += 1
}

$err = & g++.exe $GPP_ARGS 2>&1

if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
    if ($isRun -eq 1) {
        if ($isDebug -eq 1) {
            gdb.exe $EXE_NM
        } else {
            iex $EXE_NM
        }
    }
    if ($err.length -ne 0) {
        Write-Host $err -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "$err" -ForegroundColor "Red"
}
```

For example: When I try to do `cpr.ps1 HCF.cpp` it throws the following error:

> g++.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.

I have ensured that the .cpp file exists in the current working directory.

Comment: A much better idea would be to use `make`.

Comment: Yes, but the reason is I build&run only single cpp files most of the time. It would be very tedious for me to make Makefiles for each & every program I make.

Comment: You don't need to do that. And if you are compiling single  C++ files, why not just use the g++ driver?

Comment: Probably you are right, I had went too crazy & was trying to reinvent the wheel for no proper reason. Thanks for tracking me to right path. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the recommendation of using `make` rather than writing your own build script. A simple re-usable Makefile isn't that difficult to write:

```
CXX = g++.exe
CPPFLAGS ?= -O2 -Wall

# get all files whose extension begins with c and is at least 2 characters long,
# i.e. foo.cc, foo.cpp, foo.cxx, ...
# NOTE: this also includes files like foo.class, etc.
SRC = $(wildcard *.c?*)

# pick the first file from the above list and change the extension to .exe
APP = $(basename $(word 1, $(SRC))).exe

$(APP): $(SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

.PHONY: run
run: $(APP)
    @./$(APP)

.PHONY: debug
debug: $(APP)
    @gdb $(APP)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(APP)
```

`make` builds the program (if required). `make run` executes the program after building it. `make debug` runs the program in `gdb`. `make clean` deletes the program.

You can override the default CPPFLAGS by defining an environment variable:

```
$env:CPPFLAGS = '-g'
make
```